# Sorting rows that appears in multiple groups

Tags: views

I have a View where rows are grouped by a taxonomy term. The taxonomy term field accepts multiple values, so there could be cases where the same row occurs in more than one group.

For exmaple:

Group #1 - Term A

- Node 3
- Node 5
- Node 7

Group #2 - Term B

- Node 3
- Node 4
- Node 6

The problem I am facing is that in the scenario above, Node 3 has the same weight value in both groups. Therefore, if I change the weight of Node 3 in Group #1, it also gets changed in Group #2.

Is there any way to apply a unique weight to rows that occur in multiple groups?